# jQuery datepicker in Symfony2 gives 'This value is not valid.'

Tags: jquery, symfony, jquery-ui-datepicker

I added a jQuery datepicker in my symfony2 form.

twig file:

```
$('.date').datepicker({ 
    showOn: 'button', 
    buttonImageOnly: true, 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-MM-dd ',
    yearRange: "-0:+1"  
});
```

*PostType.php*

```
$builder->add('toDate','datetime',array(
                'input' => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'yy-MM-dd',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'date')
        ));
```

I tried several date formats. But I always get `This value is not valid.` when I submit. I tried to get the form errors, but it doesn't give any more information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try something like this

```
$('.date').datepicker({ 
    showOn: 'button', 
    buttonImageOnly: true, 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    yearRange: "-0:+1"  
});
```

PostType.php

```
$builder->add('toDate','date',array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
    'attr' => array('class' => 'date')
 ))
```

Comment: thats great, it works! is there a documentation for this date formats and jquery?

Comment: just to point out that this post is just great! Thanks a million Rajesh

Comment: it because MM in Symfony and mm in jQuery UI return the same

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it clear.

in jQuery UI:

```
mm = "01"
MM = "January"
```

in Symfony:

```
mm // is not valid format
MM == "01"
```

Symfony MM is same as jQuery UI mm