# jQuery datepicker in Symfony2 gives 'This value is not valid.' with chrome

Tags: symfony, google-chrome, firefox, datepicker

I have some form built with symfony 2.7 and some date fields within. I have followed the question of Ahmed SIOUANI '[jQuery datepicker in Symfony2 gives 'This value is not valid.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509378/jquery-datepicker-in-symfony2-gives-this-value-is-not-valid) 'to fix the problem of datpicker with firefox and that goes well. But now a have the message 'This value is not valid' with chrome navigator.

Here my formType :

```
...
$builder->add('dateNaissance', 'date', array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'label' => 'birth date:', 
                'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy'                    
            );
...
```

I added this script to my twig view :

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes['date']) {
                        jQuery(function($){ //on document.ready
                            $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                                changeMonth: true,
                                changeYear: true,
                                yearRange: "1980:2016"
                            });
                        })
                }
```

It seems it return empty value after submitting.
Thank you for help.

Comment: What is the submitted value in your request?

Comment: i have empty value with chrome

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after checking the posted data with chrome browser, i found that html5 datapicker return yyyy-mm-dd that dosen't correspond to the format requested by the entity in the backend.